# Laravel component is not receiving variables, no matter what i do

Tags: php, laravel

First, i have the component file, located at resources/views/component.

**game-card.blade.php**

```
@props(['game'])
<div class = 'games'>
    <a href = 'game/{{$game->id}}'> view page </a>
    <p> game: {{$game->name}} </p> <br>
    <p> genre: {{$game->genre}} </p> <br>
</div>
```

Then this component is called at my view, located in resources/views

**listing.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')
@section('list')
    <div class = 'listContainer'>
        @unless(count($games) === 0)
            @foreach($games as $game)
                //doesn't work
                <x-game-card :game = "$game"/> 
                
            @endforeach
        @else
            <p> 0 Games </p>
        @endunless
    </div>
@endsection
```

The variable `$game` is not passed in the component `<x-game-card/>`, i even tried to use short atribute syntax (<x-game-card :$game/>) but it still doesn't work.

If it matters, the file **listing.blade.php** is yielded at the file **layout.blade.php**, located in the same folder.

**layout.blade.php**

```
  <body>
<!-- Header  -->
@yield('list')

@yield('singlegame')

@include('partials._footer')
```

Answer (score 0):

For any prop that you want to pass to your component, you need to register it on the component class. In this case, the class is probably `app/View/Components/GameCard.php`

On the class, you need to do something like:

```php
class GameCard extends Component
{

    public $game;

    public function __construct($game)
    {
        $this->game = $game;
    }
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#passing-data-to-components

Comment: I just created a Component with `php artisan make:component`, and used the syntax at your answer. However, it still doesn't work

Comment: Oh, that's weird. I copied your code and didn't work for me either, but when I added those lines on the class, it worked :/

Answer (score 0):

i found the root of the problem. I just can't believe that the solution is so simple. I am going to post it here so less people make the same mistake i did

First, create the class (i personally use the command `php artisan make:component` to do that) and update it just like Nico did.

Second, when you put the <x-component in the HTML, **MAKE SURE TO NOT LEAVE ANY SPACES IN THE VARIABLE!!!**
my mistake was using  `<x-game-card :game = "$game"/>`

instead of `<x-game-card :game="$game"/>`

Comment: Anonymous component should be fine...

Comment: This is why it is so important to stick to standards and respect them 99%